# Past Perfect Continuous VS Past continuous

Tags: past-perfect, past-continuous

Do these two sentences mean the same?

1. When I arrived, Lisa was waiting for me.
2. When I arrived, Lisa had been waiting for me.

Comment: Duplicate of many; one is [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/16664/37009).

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the same because they are two differents tenses but they are very similar though (sometimes sentences with these tenses are interchangeable). In the first sentence you have *Past Continuous* and this tense puts emphasis on the course of an action in the past. For example: Manuel was playing football.

In your case is *Past Continuous* with an action happening on at a certain time in the past.

On the other hand, the *Past Perfect Continuous* puts emphasis on the course **or duration** of an action taking place **before** a certain time in the past.

The second sentence is like the past perfect itself because it is an action that takes place before a certain time in the past, I mean, Lisa had been waiting for you when you arrived. That stands for the duration of the action.

Comment: The perfect in its many forms is very complex, and the shades of meaning are subtle. There is an excellent source [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/37009) which new English learners should study closely.